# What does 'VersionCompatible32="1"' mean within a VBP file?

Tags: vb6

I have a VB6 project, when I came to check in changes to the VB6 project file I noticed that the Visual Studio 6 IDE had automatically inserted the following line:

```
VersionCompatible32="1"
```

What does this mean?

As an aside: Is there a good resource to help me make sense of the VBP file?

Comment: The VB6 manual includes a section on VBP file format, but sadly it doesn't explain the meaning of any of the entries :( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716294(v=VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `VersionCompatible32` value in the VBP file seems to be part of the binary compatibility settings of an ActiveX project, maybe the typelib it needs to be compatible with (there can be several in a library).
When my project is set to no, or just project compatibility, this value is removed.
Note that the compatibility setting itself is stored in the `CompatibleMode` value.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, I don't think it is a good idea to edit the VBP file manually. As far as I know, VersionCompatible32 is a hint about the VB(A) version that was used to save this file, probably for newer versions to recognize changes in the file format.

Comment: I'm not *really* attempting to edit the vbp file manually, its just standard practice to diff the files modified before check-in. As far as I'm concerned, I need to know why Visual Studio 6 has thought it necessary to modify the vbp file. I'm hoping that by understanding the contents of the vbp file it will help me resolve some project issues I am seeing.

Comment: I see. Then you might also be interested in the meaning of the .vbw file which will also change on every save of the project. You can set that file to be ignored by your configuration management system, it only saves the windows currently opened in the project, their layout and position.